# Joint Probability

Tags: probability, self-study

Fairly new to statistics here.  Can someone please show me how to calculate the probability that this "team" will collectively score at least 463 points?

I need to do this in Excel.

```
Player  Projection  Mean    StDev
Player A    50      49.16   21.61
Player B    54      53.14   12.54
Player C    55      54.36   14.85
Player D    55      54.52   12.27
Player E    46      45.67   22.97
Player F    48      47.86   19.31
Player G    55      54.79   12.43
Player H    54      53.46   10.82
Player I    46      45.22   22.40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that the team will score the sum of what each player scores. I further assume, that the score of each player is normally distributed with the given mean and standard deviation. Then the obvious first thing you will have to do is to sum up the normal distributions of the players. 
Luckily, adding normal distributions is easy and the rules can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

$N(\mu_X + \mu_Y, \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2)$

So you can simply add the means and add the variances, which are the squares of the standard deviations.

You thus get a normal distribution for the team score and need to look for the excel function which gives you the area under that perticular bell curve for 462.99 points. That is the probability of less then 462.99 points. 1 - that probability is what you look for.

I consider this homework, even though there is no self-study tag, therefore I explained a way to solve it without solving it totally. If this is homework, pleas add a self-study tag. If not, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you!  No, it's not homework.  It's for fantasy lineups lol.

Comment: Good for you. Still kinda self-study ;-). https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Wow! That is so easy and I've previously been using Monte Carlo simulations to figure this out.